# ¿Se puede cambiar el background del editor Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Me interesaría saber como cambiar el fondo del editor Netbeans y la verdad no tengo idea de como hacerlo, se que esto se puede en otros editores y por eso mi pregunta.

pd: Ya se que es algo tonto pero me gustaría que me dijeran.

Comment: Define background  sube una captura indicando donde quieres el fondo.

Answer (score 0):

1) Abre Netbeans y dirígete al menú Herramientas → Opciones.

2) Se mostrará una nueva ventana con varias opciones configurables. Elige la pestaña Tipos de letras y colores.

3) En la parte baja encontrarás una sección con código el cual puedes tomar como referencia para una previsualización de los cambios.

4) En el campo Categoría selecciona el apartado al cual deseas cambiar color, luego en la parte derecha encontrarás las opciones: tipo de letra, primer plano, fondo, efectos y color de efecto. Con estos parámetros puedes jugar y cambiar los colores a conveniencia.